# Common interface for fixed-length and variable-length lists in C#

Tags: c#, classes, wrapper

I am working on library project in which I am reading and writing binary files that have own file format structure. In that structure there are variable-length and fixed-length elements. My approach is to parse byte stream of such files, create corresponding objects, and then get current byte stream and write it back to file. So I need to have byte `stream <-> object` binding. The problem is very complicated file format (AFP) in which some structures are variable length and some are not. I got stuck on choosing best "list" class for storing byte streams that may be fixed-length or variable-length. My idea is to wrap such byte stream "list" in another class (composition) and allow different external objects to be passed into that class (C# array or List).

```
namespace TEST
{
    public class ByteStreamList : IList<byte>, IEnumerable<byte>
    {
        protected IList<byte> bytes = null;

        public byte this[int index] {
            get {
                return bytes[index];
            }

            set {
                bytes[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public int Count {
            get {
                return bytes.Count;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly {
            get {
                return bytes.IsReadOnly;
            }
        }

        public ByteStreamList(IList<byte> bytes)
        {
            this.bytes = bytes;
        }

        public void Add(byte item)
        {
            if (!(bytes is IReadOnlyList<byte>)) {
                bytes.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            if (!(bytes is IReadOnlyList<byte>)) {
                bytes.Clear();
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(byte item)
        {
            if (!(bytes is IReadOnlyList<byte>)) {
                return bytes.Contains(item);
            }

            return false;
        }

    // ... rest of IList<byte> and IEnumerable<byte> interface ///
}

namespace Test_CA
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ByteStreamList fixedLengthByteList = new ByteStreamList(new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC });
            ByteStreamList variableLengthByteList = new ByteStreamList(new List<byte>() { 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF });
        }
    }
}
```

With that approach (using `IList<>` class) I would need to provide some access to byte stream via `IList<>` methods. So I could let my wrapper class implement `IList<>`. That approach forces me to check if underlying "list" class is `IReadOnlyList` or not. If not, methods like `Add()` `Clear()` would be allowed. I know it is very bad approach to use `List<>` because if something will require that type I will not pass any other list/container except `List<>` .

Is it good approach with checking everytime if "list" is readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would rather use the `IList.IsFixedSize` property concerning Add, Clear, Remove, or RemoveAt actions.

Your indexer logic seems lacking.  Granted you could make a custom exception for an out-of-range index, but it will be thrown anyway.  More to my point and to align with your stated objective, the indexer setter is where you would want to check `IsReadOnly`.

I would also encourage you to add more constructors, specifically at least one for `IEnumerable<byte>` as an input parameter, but you may want the constructor to include `bool` parameters for `IsReadOnly` and `IsFixedSize`.  As you have it know accepting only another IList as input, you retain the properties of that input.  If you were to accomodate `IEnumerable<byte>` as input, you may want to allow the caller to the constructor to declare the intentions for `IsReadOnly` and `IsFixedSize`.

Consider this possible signature:

`public ByteStreamList(IEnumerable<byte> bytes, bool isReadOnly, bool isFixedSize)`

This poses a challenge of what if someone calls this with an `IList` with different properties than what is passed in the constructor?  What if they pass in a fixed-size, read-only IList with:

`var sbl = new ByteStreamList(fixedSizeReadOnlyIList, false, false);`

The constructor would have to compose the underlying `bytes` accordingly and not just simply assign `fixedSizeReadOnlyIList` to `bytes`.  Could be a fun challenge.

Comment: I tried to add exceptions for `Add()`, `Clear()`, `Remove()` and `RemoveAt()` methods, but I am not sure if such code would look pretty & clear. I like idea of passing `bool`s into constructor and selecting corresponding behavior. Would be it clear & OK to create static methods that wraps `(IEnumberable<byte>, bool, bool)` constructor and passes values for bool fields? `BSL.CreateFixedSizeList(IEnumberable<byte>)` or `BSL.CreateReadOnlyList(IEnumberable<byte>)`, `BSL.CreateFixedSizeReadOnlyList(IEnumberable<byte>)` ? Maybe examine if input list is really RO or FS in those static methods?